# Invariant Violation when importing as alias

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

When importing a component as an alias I receive this error:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Divider`.

```
import { Divider as MuiDivider} from 'material-ui/Divider'

const Divider = () => <MuiDivider style={{margin: '1em 2em'}} />

<Divider />
```

This works:

```
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider'

<Divider />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mixing up two different parts of the ES6 import syntax:

```
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider'
```

and

```
import {Divider} from 'material-ui/Divider'
```

are not the same.

The first imports the default export (which plays well with CommonJS modules as well), whereas the second looks for a named export caleld `Divider`.

You can however give your default import any name you want:

```
import MuiDivider from 'material-ui/Divider'
```

Comment: Thank you.  So use of `as` is to alias a named export?

Comment: @BAR: Yes. As mentioned, you already can name default exports/imports however you want.